# How to do a partial search in Hibernate Panache

Tags: kotlin, jpa, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I'm trying to do a partial search using Hibernate Panache. I'm building a backend using Quarkus and Kotlin. Now when my frontend gives me a search string I'd like to return all partial results.

I have the following query:

```
repository.find("firstName LIKE '%?1%'", value)
```

Now I've tried a couple of variations of this, including one with the .list() method.

Does anyone know how I should handle this?

Comment: What do you mean with "partial results"? What kind of SQL query would you like to run on the db?

Comment: When I search for "aar" as a first name in the users column I'd like to return all rows starting with "aar", so for example "Aaron"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
repository.list( "lower(firstName) LIKE ?1", value.toLowerCase() + "%" );
```

But if you need more complex full-text queries, I would suggest to have a look at [Hibernate Search](https://hibernate.org/search/)